# autoplot does not accept ts object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a ts object and then I am trying to run it through autoplot. Execution gives me an error:

> autoplot(pts, facets = TRUE)
>   Error: Objects of type mts/ts/matrix not supported by autoplot.

I have already checked the type of the object , and it is ts and autoplot is supposed to make a plot out of the ts object. I also tried to run other built in ts object (USAccDeaths) , but it gives me same error

library(ggplot2)

pts <-  ts(data = Popcopys[,-1], start = c(2006,1),frequency = 1 )

autoplot(pts)
autoplot(USAccDeaths)

A plot of TS is expected , but what I get is this error:

> autoplot(pts)
>   Error: Objects of type mts/ts/matrix not supported by autoplot.
>   autoplot(USAccDeaths)
>   Error: Objects of type ts not supported by autoplot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)
autoplot(USAccDeaths)
```

Following https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfortify/vignettes/plot_ts.html :
"{ggfortify} lets {ggplot2} know how to interpret ts objects"

Comment: Thank you, in the mean while, I installed 'forecast' package. That packadge has its own autoplot. Now , I am trying your solution and it wont let me select the ggplot's autoplot  ( I am using ggplot2::autoplot(ts, facets=  T)) ,  it will not recognize the facets,any idea how to fix this  ?

Comment: No, because I have no idea what "ts" looks like.

Comment: Did not work for me
I tried
library(ggfortify) but got an error message:
Error in library(ggfortify) : es gibt kein Paket namens ‘ggfortify (meaning that there is not package with that name)

Comment: @PeterBe comonly this means you have not installed the package yet. Before calling any none base R package/library you have to download and install de packages. This can be done with one simple call install.packages("ggfortify").

Answer (score 2):

If you have ggplot or tidyverse loaded into your environment along with the forecast library both have an autoplot function.

You will need to specify which you are attempting to use.

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)

data <-read.csv('C:/users/person/desktop/data.csv')

ts_df <-ts(data, start = 2018, frequency = 52)

forecast::autoplot(ts_df[,'Column_name'])
```